# Electric field lines?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

Obviously, electric field lines for 2 charges, one stronger than the other, behave like this: https://www4.uwsp.edu/physastr/kmenning/images/pop4.19.f.19.gif.
Is there a way to measure angles for particular field lines?
For example, the field line at theta=0 is just a straight line going from the positive charge to the negative one. Similarly, theta= 180 goes from the positive charge to negative infinity. Are there similar rules for some arbitrary value of theta? Do any theta values do something interesting besides theta=0 and 180?

Answer (score 4):

If the system is **reduced to two dimension** or equivalently infinite long wire, we can use complex potential flow:

$$f(z)=\phi(x,y)+i\psi(x,y)$$

where $\phi(x,y)$ is the "velocity" potential (or electric potential) and $\psi(x,y)$ the stream function.

The complex "velocity" field is given by

$$w=\overline{f'(z)}$$

where $f(z)$ is analytic so that $\phi(x,y)$ and $\psi(x,y)$ satisfy Cauchy-Riemann relation.  Hence $\phi$, $\psi$ are harmonic and therefore satisfy Laplace's equation.  That is

$$w
=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}
=\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}-i\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}$$

For a single charge at the origin,

\begin{align}
  f(z) &= \frac{\lambda}{2\pi \epsilon_0} \ln z \\
  \phi(x,y) &= \frac{\lambda}{2\pi \epsilon_0} \ln r \\
  \psi(x,y) &= \frac{\lambda}{2\pi \epsilon_0} \theta \\
\end{align}

Assume $+2q$ and $-q$ locating at $(-a,0)$ and $(a,0)$ respectively,

\begin{align}
  f(z) &= \frac{q}{ \pi \epsilon_0} \ln (z+a)-
          \frac{q}{2\pi \epsilon_0} \ln (z-a) \\
  \phi(x,y) &=
  \frac{q}{2\pi \epsilon_0}
  \ln \frac{[(x+a)^2+y^2]^2}{(x-a)^2+y^2} \\
  \psi(x,y) &=
  \frac{q}{2\pi \epsilon_0}
  \tan^{-1} \frac{y(x^2+y^2-2ax-3a^2)}{x^3+xy^2+ax^2+3ay^2-a^2x-a^3}
\end{align}

> The equipotential and field lines can be expressed as
>   \begin{align}
>   e^{\alpha} &= \frac{[(x+a)^2+y^2]^2}{(x-a)^2+y^2} \\
>   \tan \beta &=
>   \frac{y(x^2+y^2-2ax-3a^2)}{x^3+xy^2+ax^2+3ay^2-a^2x-a^3}
> \end{align}

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. How do you determine the function f as being lambda / 2 pi epsilon_0 * ln (z)?

Comment: See some examples [*here*](https://complex-analysis.com/content/complex_potential_basic_examples.html), use integration to check the propotional constant where $\lambda$ is the linear charge density.

Answer (score 2):

At large enough distance the charge distribution can be well approximated as a monopole, so the open field lines should distribute themselves evenly around the circle.

Comment: I see. Does that always happen at a specific theta value, or is it fairly arbitrary?

Comment: You showed that for certain orientations of the starting lines you can nail (at least) one down. You can probably use that to establish a rule of some kind.