# Stagnation points of combination of line sink and line source

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

I've got the complex potential of a flow consisting of a line sink at $z=-a$ and a line source at $z=a$ both of equal strength. I want to find the stagnation points but when I differentiate I get no solution. This is the complex potential I have got: $$\frac{Q}{2\pi}(log(z-a)-log(z+a))$$

May have got the complex potential wrong, any hints?

Comment: What makes you think that there *is* a stagnation point to begin with? Have you tried plotting the velocity field?

Answer (score 0):

> When two *"charges"* are **equal and opposite**, there'll be no neutral point at which the electric fields from the charges balance each other.  Similarly, for source and sink with equal strengths, there's no stagnation point.  See more on 
>   [**bipolar coordinates**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_coordinates).

If you see another case [**here**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/382905/electric-field-lines/383068#383068), there'll be a neutral point such that more than one field lines meet together with other than singular points.

[image]

In the above case: $2Q$ and $-Q$ at $z=-1$ and $z=1$ respectively, the red curve is the equipotential whereas the blue curve is the field line such that they meet at the neutral point $z=3$.